# Cant get my sorting rule right for std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have trying to use a class as a key in an std::map. I have read documentations and I know I have to type some sort of sorting rule because my std::map is a binary search tree. The problem arise because the class key have another classes in it. Can someone get me some advice how to build the operators?

MasterRenderer file

```
std::map<TexturedModel, std::vector<Entity>> entites;
void MasterRenderer::processEntity(Entity entity)
{
TexturedModel model = entity.getModel();
auto search = entites.find(model);
if (search != entites.end()) {
    //found
    entites[model].emplace_back(entity);
}
else {
    //not found
    entites[model].emplace_back(entity);
}
std::cout << entites[model].size() << std::endl;
}
```

TexturedModel.h

```
    TexturedModel(RawModel model, ModelTextures 
    texture)
    :m_model(model), m_texture(texture) {

};
    friend bool operator<(const TexturedModel& m, 
    const 
    TexturedModel& m2) {
    return m.m_model < m2.m_model || m.m_model == 
    m2.m_model && m.m_texture < m2.m_texture;
    }
private:
    RawModel m_model;
    ModelTextures m_texture;

};
```

Rawmodel.h

```
    unsigned int VaoID;
    unsigned int Vertecies;

RawModel(unsigned int vaoID, unsigned int 
vertecies)
    :VaoID(vaoID), Vertecies(vertecies) {};

friend bool operator <(const RawModel& rhs, const 
RawModel& rhs2)
{
    return rhs.get() < rhs2.get();
}

friend bool operator ==(const RawModel& rhs, const 
RawModel& rhs2)
{
    return rhs.get() == rhs2.get();
}

const RawModel* get() const {
    return this;
}
```

ModelTextures.h

```
    ModelTextures(unsigned int ID)
    :textureID(ID) {};
friend bool operator<(const ModelTextures& rhs, 
const ModelTextures& rhs2)
{
    return rhs.get() < rhs2.get();
}
const ModelTextures* get() const{
    return this;
}

private:
    unsigned int textureID;
    float shineDamper = 1.0f;
    float reflectivity = 0.0f;
};
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using `std::tie` to implement `operator<`. It automatically gives you a lexicographical ordering. That is, `std::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b, lhs.c) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c)`.

Comment: what is the problem? do you get an error? unexpected output?

Comment: see first example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie assuming the parts also have operator< (basically what Justin already said)

Comment: @Justin Okay I will try that but what should I put instead of a, b and c?

Comment: @user463035818, Sorry didnt really explain whats not working. I am trying to sort my entities of the textured model they are using. But the map cant use TexturedModel to store the entitys.

Comment: "But the map cant use TexturedModel to store the entitys" why?

Comment: @KennyOstrom, yes I will take a look at that!:)

Comment: Please include the error message verbatim in the question

Comment: @user463035818 because I havent fix the operator< correctly, When I using .find(texturemodel) the map cant finde any key with that name. In my main I am sending the same entitys 4 time and they use the same texturedmodel, so something is wrong.

Comment: there is no `main` in your code. Please read about  [mcve]

Comment: @user463035818 `main` is definitely not required for an MCVE. That said, this question definitely needs an MCVE.

Comment: @Justin I think I make a mcve for this one

Comment: @user463035818 Ill do that

Comment: @Justin no `main` is usually not necessarily reuqired, but if the problem is "In my main I am [...], so something is wrong" then it is ;)

Comment: Thanks all guys that you tryed to help me out with this, I appreciate your help much!

Answer (score 2):

```
friend bool operator<(const ModelTextures& rhs, 
const ModelTextures& rhs2)
{
    return rhs.get() < rhs2.get();
}
const ModelTextures* get() const{
    return this;
}
```

this orders by address of the object, not content.  That violates the requirements of `std::map`.

```
friend auto as_tie(const ModelTexture& m) {
  return std::tie(m.textureID, m.shineDamper, m.reflexivity);
}
friend bool operator<(const ModelTextures& rhs, 
const ModelTextures& rhs2)
{
    return as_tie(rhs) < as_tie(lhs);
}
```

repeat this pattern for `TexturedModel` and `RawModel`.

If you are stuck in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you have to manually write the return type of `as_tie` or use `decltype`.

```
friend auto as_tie(const ModelTexture& m)
-> decltype(std::tie(m.textureID, m.shineDamper, m.reflexivity))
{
  return std::tie(m.textureID, m.shineDamper, m.reflexivity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think im stuck in c++11. I fell dumb but how do I manually write a return type?

Comment: @anttton `decltype` solution added, just requires some copy/paste.